# Django models fail in unittest, but not in shell

Tags: django

I am running a test on my new Django code.  I have the following models:

```
class Places(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    confirmed = models.BooleanField()
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.address

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Places" # to prevent the prefixes from being added on
```

When I do this in the manage.py shell I get the correct response :

```
from my_app.models import Places

Places.objects.get(name='home').confirmed

>>> True
```

When this same code is performed in the my app under a unittest (manage.py test myapp) I get the error:

```
Places matching query does not exist django
```

When I tried with PDB I found that Django is reading the database as being empty (an empty set) and not as storing any data.

I also tried RAW SQL in the code and that failed as well, but worked in shell.

I checked with the database in sql itself and the data exists.  I performed the equivalent SQL code and it returns True as well.

Is this a bug in Django?

Comment: please, print result of `Places.objects.filter(name='home').count()`

Comment: It's 0 .  The RAW SQL shows nothing as well do it must be an issue with django "seeing" the database and the information in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit tests are always executed against a new empty database. Have you created the data within the setup step of your test, or provided a data fixture?

Comment: I just figured this out as you where typing... yes :)